# eclipse shortcut only active in package explorer

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I want a shortcut(e.g ctrl+o) only active in package explorer view，so that I can use this shortcut in the main java editor view of another purpose(open quick outline view).
I know there is a way in the shortcut setting that I can set the shortcut only active in some context.
But actually I can't find the selection which named `package explorer` in `when` setting in the `shortcut setting`(the image below),so is there any other way I can solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse keybindings can be customized in General > Keys preference page.
Key bindings can vary based on the current context of Eclipse. It is possible to assign the same shortcut to different parts of Eclipse.
See [Eclipse Key Bindings](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftkeybindings.htm)

Comment: But I can't find the selection which named "package explorer" in "when" setting in the shortcut setting.I want the shortcut only active in "package explorer" which the context setting doesn't offer in the shortcut setting.